# Logic Circuits And Equations Issue - Multiply Binary Number By 3

Tags: computer-arithmetic

I am trying to build a logic circuit that multiplies any 4 digit binary number by 3.
I know that if I multiply/divide number by 2 it moves left/right the digits, but what I'm 
 doing with multiply by 3?

1. How to extract the equations that multiply the digits?
2. I need to use a full adder?

I would like to get some advice. Thanks!

EDIT

I would like to get comments about my circuit of Multiplier 4 digits binary number by 3.

[image: multiplier]

Comment: I cannot understand your circuit at all. What are these rectangular boxes? Aren't you supposed to have 6 bits for the output?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I see is to note that $3n=2n+n$, so copy $n$, shift it one to the left, and add back to $n$

Comment: ok, what I need to do now? I dont know how to implement it on a logic circuit?

Comment: That is electrical engineering design, which I can't help with.  There is an electrical engineering stack exchange site.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Here is the most related question from Electrial Engineering Stack Exchange: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72306/multiply-4-digit-binary-number-by-3-circuit. Good luck!